# Obter nome do BD em uma conexão mysql

Tags: php

Bom faço uma conexão com o BD mysql assim:

```
// Conecta-se ao banco do servidor
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '123', 'teste');
Query($mysqli, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

Como posso recuperar o nome do BD `teste` através da variável `$mysqli` que contem a conexão.

Comment: O último parâmetro passado para a função "mysqli_connect" é o nome do banco, não seria melhor você armazenar isso é uma variável global? Assim você não precisaria fazer uma consulta para saber o nome do banco.

Comment: Bom isso Resolve sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [database()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_database) do MySQL ela retorna o nome do banco de dados da conexão.

```
SELECT database()
```

No php com MySQLi fica assim:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'db003-producao');
$result = $db->query('select database() as db');
$registro = $result->fetch_array();
echo $registro[0];
```